# SEO Duplicate Content with AWS S3 with CloudFront Static Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I've done a classical setup for a static website using S3, CloudFront and Route53, however I'm getting a maddening error I hadn't encountered before.

So there's 2 buckets, example.net and www.example.net, with the non-www one having the Static Hosting on and the actual files, the www one just the redirect to HTTPS.

On the Route53 side, I've got the A record for mysite.com as an Alias for the CloudFront distribution, with the www CNAME pointing back to mysite.com

The CloudFront distribution uses the non-www bucket as the origin, but lists as alternative both www and non-www sites, with the Redirect HTTP to HTTPS option on.

All of this successfully allows me to have the website functioning, but on the SEO side I'm having a duplicate content issue because all of the alias successfully resolve as so

---

http non-www address -->   https non-ww address (HTTP to HTTPS, good)

https non-www address -->   https non-www address (Straight HTTPS, good)

---

http www address -->   https www address (Works, but fails redirecting to non-www domain)

https www address -->   https www address (Works, but fails redirecting to non-www domain)

---

Everything I try seemingly breaks the www side (like removing the alias on the CloudFront distribution, or switching the CNAME for an A that points to the CloudFront URL). 
Thing is, I had done this previously with a GoDaddy DNS with the Forwarding feature, which from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/720152/how-to-configure-aws-route-53-to-get-equivalent-of-domain-forwarding-with-maskin) answer I understand is a reverse proxy rather then a core DNS feature.

However, I found [this](https://medium.com/@davidgurevich_11928/cloudfront-as-a-reverse-proxy-fb6a8dcbed96) medium article on how to use CloudFront as a reverse proxy, but I can't understand how to apply it to this scenario.

Can anyone help me, please?, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are basically saying both `http www address` and `https www address` should be redirecting to `https non-www address`.

To reference the domain names easily, let's assume the `www address` is `www.example.com`, and the `non-www address` is `example.com`.

Here is my proposed solution to you problem.

1. Change the CNAME dns record of `www.example.com` to an ALAS record pointing to your `non-www` S3 bucket.
2. Configure your `non-www` S3 bucket as a static website and let it redirect all incoming requests to `example.com` using https protocol.

Comment: sorry about the names, reputation did not let me post it like that.
I've made change #1 assuming you mean changing CNAME for an A record.
For switch #2 testing seems it returns a NXLOOKUP response but on the browser it doesn't go anywhere, any ideas?

Comment: ok, after taking some time it seems like it works, however none of the images in the page end up loading because they get 301'd then get the "Too Many Redirects" errors

Comment: Could you post the request details in the browser's network console?

Comment: Hi!, I decided to give Route53 some time to process the changes, and now everything works. I still get an issue when rewriting https www.example.com, but I assume this is more an issue with the SSL config.
I'm marking this as the accepted answer, many thanks!